# Pandas squash data frame based on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading from an API which returns JSON
I am using

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
flatten = json_normalize(data['results'])
```

To flatten the JSON and now the output is like

```
                                     breakdowns                 metric                  time         value   
0      [{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'ios'}]      fb_ad_network_imp    2018-08-29T07:00:00+0000  12
1  [{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'android'}]      fb_ad_network_imp    2018-08-29T07:00:00+0000  32
2      [{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'ios'}]  fb_ad_network_request    2018-08-29T07:00:00+0000  33    
3  [{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'android'}]  fb_ad_network_request    2018-08-29T07:00:00+0000  132
```

now I want to squash these 4 rows into 2 based on the platform, something like this:

```
           platform    date         clicks     impressions
0          ios         2018-08-29   33         12
1          android     2018-08-29   132        32
```

I have also mapped these names:

`fb_ad_network_request` -> `clicks`
`fb_ad_network_imp` -> `impressions`

what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using `pivot_table` after flatten the `dict`

```
dddd['platform']=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in dddd.breakdowns]).value.values
dddd.pivot_table(index=['platform','time'],columns='metric',values='value',aggfunc=sum).reset_index()
Out[237]: 
metric platform        time  fb_ad_network_imp  fb_ad_network_request
0       android  2018-08-29                 32                    132
1           ios  2018-08-29                 12                     33
```

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
tmp = pd.Series([i[0].get('value', None) for i in df.breakdowns]).rename('platform')

mapping = {
    'columns': {
        'fb_ad_network_request': 'clicks',
        'fb_ad_network_imp': 'impressions',
        'time': 'date',
    }
}
```

#### Using `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
(df.join(tmp).groupby(['platform', df.time.dt.date, 'metric'])
    .value.sum().unstack().reset_index().rename(**mapping))
```

```
metric platform        date  impressions  clicks
0       android  2018-08-29           32     132
1           ios  2018-08-29           12      33
```

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'breakdowns': [[{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'ios'}],
                   [{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'android'}],
                   [{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'ios'}],
                   [{u'key': u'platform', u'value': u'android'}]],
    'metric': ['fb_ad_network_imp'] * 2 + ['fb_ad_network_request'] * 2,
    'time': ['2018-08-29T07:00:00+0000'] * 4,
    'value': [12, 32, 33, 132]
})
df['time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time'])
```

**Solution**

This assumes that the `time` column holds timestamps, and then uses the `dt` accessor method to get the dates and assign it to a new column in the chained dataframe.

I used a lambda function to get the platform from the breakdowns column, and then group on those values together with the date and metric.  The metric is unstacked so that each will be in separate columns, the index is reset and columns are renamed to the desired format.

```
result = (
    df
    .assign(date=df['time'].dt.date)
    .groupby([df['breakdowns'].apply(lambda x: x[0].get('value')), 'date', 'metric'])
    ['value']
    .sum()
    .unstack('metric')
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={
        'breakdowns': 'platform',
        'fb_ad_network_request': 'clicks',
        'fb_ad_network_imp': 'impressions'
    })
)
result.columns.name = None

>>> result
  platform        date  impressions  clicks
0  android  2018-08-29           32     132
1      ios  2018-08-29           12      33
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `pandas.Series` from a dictionary comprehesion

```
m0 = dict(fb_ad_network_imp='impressions', fb_ad_network_request='clicks')
flatten.time = pd.to_datetime(flatten.time).dt.floor('D')

s = pd.Series({
    (b[0]['value'], t, m0[m]): v for b, m, t, v in flatten.values
})

s.rename_axis(['platform', 'date', None]).unstack().reset_index()

  platform       date  clicks  impressions
0  android 2018-08-29     132           32
1      ios 2018-08-29      33           12
```

---

Similarly

```
m0 = dict(fb_ad_network_imp='impressions', fb_ad_network_request='clicks')

def f(tup):
  b = tup.breakdowns[0]['value']
  t = pd.to_datetime(tup.time).floor('D')
  m = m0[tup.metric]
  v = tup.value
  return ((b, t, m), v)

s = pd.Series(dict(map(f, flatten.itertuples())))

s.rename_axis(['platform', 'date', None]).unstack().reset_index()

  platform       date  clicks  impressions
0  android 2018-08-29     132           32
1      ios 2018-08-29      33           12
```